# Error when save Object - Optimistic lock exception on saving entity

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mongodb

I just doing simple transactions like :

1. findByVariable(String variable);
2. manipulate the data, then
3. save(data);

but i got Exception like this

```
org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException: Optimistic lock exception on saving entity: Document{{dataKey=A, lastValue=XXX, version=1, createdDate=Mon Apr 13 21:53:25 WIB 2020, updatedDate=Mon Apr 13 22:34:28 WIB 2020, _class=SomeData}} to collection some_data
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate.lambda$doUpdate$65(ReactiveMongoTemplate.java:1819)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:177)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:242)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.SingleResultObservableToPublisher$1.onNext(SingleResultObservableToPublisher.java:42)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.ObservableToPublisher$1.onNext(ObservableToPublisher.java:66)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.AbstractSubscription.onNext(AbstractSubscription.java:142)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.AbstractSubscription.processResultsQueue(AbstractSubscription.java:217)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.AbstractSubscription.tryProcessResultsQueue(AbstractSubscription.java:172)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.SingleResultCallbackSubscription$1.onResult(SingleResultCallbackSubscription.java:48)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollectionImpl$4.onResult(MongoCollectionImpl.java:647)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollectionImpl$4.onResult(MongoCollectionImpl.java:641)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollectionImpl$10.onResult(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1138)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollectionImpl$10.onResult(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1122)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.OperationExecutorImpl$2$1$1.onResult(OperationExecutorImpl.java:140)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper$ConnectionReleasingWrappedCallback.onResult(OperationHelper.java:432)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.addBatchResult(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:527)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.access$1600(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:72)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$6.onResult(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:507)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$6.onResult(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:479)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor$2.onResult(DefaultServer.java:245)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl$1.onResult(CommandProtocolImpl.java:85)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection$1.onResult(DefaultConnectionPool.java:467)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection$2.onResult(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:111)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:399)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:376)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:677)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:644)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:514)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:511)
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.readAsync(NettyStream.java:233)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.readAsync(InternalStreamConnection.java:511)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.access$1000(InternalStreamConnection.java:76)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:634)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:619)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:514)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:511)
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.readAsync(NettyStream.java:233)
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.handleReadResponse(NettyStream.java:263)
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.access$800(NettyStream.java:69)
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$InboundBufferHandler.channelRead0(NettyStream.java:322)
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$InboundBufferHandler.channelRead0(NettyStream.java:319)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have `@Version` already on my Entity and when i was debuging, i saw that the version is greater than the existing value in database. in database the `version` is `0` and exactly when i try to `save(data)` the `version` has increased to `1` which is correct.

I have already read the spring docs about [Mongodb Optimistic Locking](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#reference) and i think i didn't do anything wrong :')

Please take a look my entity below

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = CollectionName.SOME_DATA)
public class SomeData implement Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @Field(value = "_id")
  private String id;

  @Version
  @Field(value = "version")
  private Long version;

  @CreatedDate
  @Field(value = "createdDate")
  private Date createdDate;

  @LastModifiedDate
  @Field(value = "updatedDate")
  private Date updatedDate;

  @Indexed
  @Field(value = "dataKey")
  private String dataKey;

  @Indexed
  @Field(value = "lastValue")
  private String lastValue;

}
```

Comment: are you using @Version from Spring-Data `org.springframework.data.annotation.Version`? or from JPA spec `javax.persistence.Version` ?

Comment: yes i use `@Version` from `org.springframework.data.annotation.Version`

Comment: any logs ? any reproducer or git repo could be useful

Comment: I've already provide the logs on my post, please wait i will create new repo

Comment: Talked about some kind of SQL logging (ok no sql here because Mongo but you get the idea)

Comment: Please feel free to checkout and pull request https://github.com/black-lotus/study-spring-netty

Comment: I've already fix this issue, but i still does not know what happens and what is the real issue is :') since in my another project i've the same code (entity) and all works like a charm, only in this project failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case someone encounter the same issue, on our legacy project we using spring data mongo version `org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.10.23.RELEASE` and on this legacy code we also overriding the mongo `id`.

And it seem the root cause is because we force the spring data mongo to `_id` instead `id` this make the mongo object converter to save `id` as String instead of mongo object. The solution is simply remove `@Field(value = "_id")` or dont modify `id` as other string alias. But if you want to make alias for this `id` I suppose you need extend the mongo object converter class `MappingMongoConverter` and make your own implementation.

note: the unexpected behavior happen because on the new version of spring data mongo have different implementation on mongo object converter `MappingMongoConverter` class when handling alias for mongo `id`. If the alias not exactly `id` then when saving data `id` will be saved as String